# Memory usage caused by MySQL or Apache?

Tags: memory

[image: my vps memory usage]
<sub>(source: [fileden.com](http://www.fileden.com/files/2012/9/14/3347302/my%20usage.png))</sub>

Here is a screenshot of my usage today on an idle unfinished cms drupal site with a maximum of 14 added modules besides core and no activity or users.

As you can see I am at my limit which is crazy so I need to limit memory usage of apache and mysql and php because my VPS is smallest one which should suit my current needs.

My system file my.cnf does not have a list of parameters as I've seen posted elsewhere but this is the file which apparently will lessen usage of memory amongst other things I've read like memory leaks and apache MPM workers vs apache prefork which seems to be what I have.

So how can I significantly reduce memory usage without removing apache or php5?

I am using mysql version 5.1.66 and looks like innodb and show variable yabbit.net/mysql.txt

Comment: Are you using MyISAM, InnoDB or both? And what version of MySQL are you running? And could you post (pastebin or something) the output of all MySQL variables? (e.g. `mysql -e "show variables" > /path/to/outputfile`. And have you looked at other similar questions like [this one](http://serverfault.com/questions/93693/mysql-how-do-i-get-my-maximum-possible-memory-usage-down)?

Comment: mysql 5.1.66 looks like only Innodb.

Comment: Looks good. Caches are set fairly small (8MB InnoDB, 8MB MyISAM) as with default 5.1 MySQL. I don't think MySQL is causing this memory usage. You could verify that with http://mysqltuner.pl (download, run, report back the `Maximum possible memory usage:`) Have you locked down Apache MPM-Prefork to not scale to ~ 150 x 20MB as with Debian default for example? What is your `MaxClients` setting there? And can you be quantitative about "VPS is smallest one"?

Comment: Basic 1 virtual CPU 
256 MB
15 GB
60 GB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm suspecting that your Apache configuration is the culprit here, instead of your MySQL configuration. The current MySQL settings should not get it beyond about 50MB total (typically even lower I think).

However, from the configuration of Apache you posted in the comments along with the fact that your VPS only provides 256 MB of memory, I see that a setting of

```
MaxClients       256
```

for the Prefork MPM is *way* too much for such a machine. On my Debian Squeeze webservers I see about 20MB usage per fork, so about 15 connections will already consume all the memory in your machine. It's not hard to get so many concurrent connections and as a result processes will be killed, probably, or a lot of swap will be used. Result: disfunctional server or slow service response respectively.

I suggest you to either:

- Scale down your prefork configuration significantly to for example this:

  ```
  <IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
      StartServers         10
      MinSpareServers      5
      MaxSpareServers      15
      MaxClients           15
      MaxRequestsPerChild  2000
  </IfModule>
  ```

  And live with the fact you can't serve more than about 8 concurrent visitors (usually two client connections per browser). This is a limitation of the amount of memory in combination with the chosen LAMP configuration.
- Move to PHP-FPM, set up a small pool and move to the worker MPM or even another web server such as nginx. The worker MPM uses threads that share memory, rather than forks, which don't. This should allow you to handle more concurrent visitors.

Comment: Thanks for that help! I will see how I go with scaling it down because the other option will take me many hours to figure out.At the moment it is the slowest delivery in the history of mankind- embarrassingly slow. Lucky not live. Thanks again.

Comment: and following this http://www.hosting.com/support/linux/tuning-the-apache-prefork-mpm  I included ServerLimit and made it 15 equal to MaxClients. Still plan on upgrading ram.

Comment: so made mine startservers 2; minspare & maxspare 3; clients &server 15 and 1000 maxresquests